# How to create or configure Filehandler in java to logic my logs in different executions?

Tags: java, logging, filehandler

You may think it a stupid question, but surely I found no specification for it.

I have a mini-program that needs to log success and failures upon execution and I need the log to be kept apart from default ones so I can easily read it every time. Originally I put:

```
Logger.getLogger("Success").addHandler(new FileHandler("var/success.log", true));
```

My intention was to have a growing log and that every time I executed the program, the log would be growing. When I look at the log, it actually just has a lot of  headers, once for each time I executed that line, even if no log was saved. I am pretty sure this isn't how it should work, I don't have 1 unique big log anymore but a lot of them in a single file, and switching to another formatter doesn't feel like a solution at all (i still need XML).

One solution I am currently searching for is to open a fresh file at every execution.
The Pattern in the constructor doesn't seem to help with this. %u only test for already open or impossible to write, but with or without append enabled, an existing file won't stop this handler. And for %g, a rotating, it just rotates on size but the same I don't identify the previous log problem still happens.

is there a way to get there by modifying the `Logger`, `LogManager`, the constructor or the `Filehandler`? A my-own and specific solution using Files (or Path or File or whatever) to check for every combination before opening the logger doesn't seem efficient and its something I really don't really want to worry about.

Also, is there a way to get the `FileHander` to actually read the file input and CONTINUE with the log where it was left, instead of creating a new one with new headers?

This seconds question, although it fits my needs better, seems harder to get (but what would I know?), so I can work with the first one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Originally I put:
>
> `Logger.getLogger("Success").addHandler(new FileHandler("var/success.log", true));`

Some things you'll want to improve in your JUL coding are:

1. Hold on to the logger in a [static final hard reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923754/selenium-many-logs-how-to-remove).
2. Use an absolute path or a token that [resolves to an absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376223/java-util-logger-not-writing-to-file/56380338#56380338) for the filehandler.
3. Use a static block so you don't create and add multiple file handlers to the logger.

> My intention was to have a growing log and that every time I executed the program, the log would be growing. When I look at the log, it actually just has a lot of headers, once for each time I executed that line, even if no log was saved. I am pretty sure this isn't how it should work, I don't have 1 unique big log anymore but a lot of them in a single file, and switching to another formatter doesn't feel like a solution at all (i still need XML).
>
> [snip]
>
> Also, is there a way to get the FileHander to actually read the file input and CONTINUE with the log where it was left, instead of creating a new one with new headers?

That is how it works. [The cause and solution are documented in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669103/what-is-the-correct-way-of-logging-in-an-xml-from-two-different-classes-for-no/17998479#17998479).  Here is a [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359166/java-logging-using-gethead-with-append/34360219#34360219) for CSV but would work the same for XML.  Extend the XMLFormatter and override getHead and getTail.

> One solution I am currently searching for is to open a fresh file at every execution. The Pattern in the constructor doesn't seem to help with this. %u only test for already open or impossible to write, but with or without append enabled, an existing file won't stop this handler. And for %g, a rotating, it just rotates on size but the same I don't identify the previous log problem still happens.

You are creating the FileHandler from code so you can simply code up logic to create a unique file name yourself.

```
new FileHandler("var/success" + System.nanoTime() + ".log", true);
```